# Next JS Seo with static pages, SSR Pages and Client Side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apollo

I am using Apollo GraphQL with Next JS, and there are three ways I can go about querying my data and rendering it. One is using Static Rendering, using `getStaticProps()` looking something like this.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: gql`
        query Countries {
          countries {
            code
            name
            emoji
          }
        }
      `,
    });

    return {
      props: {
        countries: data.countries.slice(0, 4),
      },
   };
}
```

This is just fine but I can also use `getServerSideProps` like so

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query Countries {
        countries {
          code
          name
          emoji
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      countries: data.countries.slice(0, 4),
    },
  };
}
```

and Finally I can use client side rendering with

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

// components/ClientOnly.js

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function ClientOnly({ children, ...delegated }) {
  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!hasMounted) {
    return null;
  }

  return <div {...delegated}>{children}</div>;
}

// components/Countries.js

import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

const QUERY = gql`
  query Countries {
    countries {
      code
      name
      emoji
    }
  }
`;

export default function Countries() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);

  if (loading) {
    return ...
  }

  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }

  const countries = data.countries.slice(0, 4);

  return (
    <div className={styles.grid}>
      {countries.map((country) => (
        ...
          <p>
            {country.code} - {country.emoji}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem arises when I want to be performant in the sense that, let's say my home page has some static content that won't be updated that much, so I can use `getStaticProps()` but it will also require some data that needs `getServerSideProps()` because the data will be changing quite often.

With next you cannot use them in combination with each other on the same page, so my thought was I could use them with a client rendered component like `<ClientOnly><Countries></ClientOnly>`  but I've been reading that the code done client rendered won't be read by SEO.

I guess I am just worried about doing everything via `getServerSiderProps()` because I would think there could be a lot of requests, so I would try and design the code to use static and dynamic, but I would still want SEO to work properly. This issue is outlined partially in NEXT JS github here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11424

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Should I just fetch all my queries through `getServerSideProps()`?

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok for your website to display cached content while it builds a new version you should use getStaticProps() with the revalidate property. This will trigger a functionality called ISR (Incremental Static Regeneration).

If SEO is important for your website, try to avoid getServerSideProps().

read more at: https://vercel.com/docs/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration